# Гайки и болты

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте.

С помощью метода быстрой сортировки работающего по принципу **разделяй и властвуй** решить следующую задачу.
"Гайки и болты":
Неорганизованный плотник имеет смешанный набор N гаек и N болтов. Цель состоит в том, чтобы найти соответствующие пары гаек и болтов. Каждая гайка соответствует точно одному болту, и каждый болт соответствует точно одной гайке. Соединяя гайку и болт между собой, плотник может узнать из них больше (однако он не может сравнивать непосредственно две гайки или два болта). 
Разработайте алгоритм для этой задачи, который использует в среднем N log(N) сравнений.

Метод быстрой сортировки:

```
    private void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start >= end) return;
        int pivot = array[start];
        int i = start;
        int j = end;
        int temp = 0;

        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (array[i] < pivot)
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot)
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (start < j)
        {
            quickSort(array, start, j);
        }
        if (i < end)
        {
            quickSort(array, i, end);
        }
    }
```

Прошу помощи в решении задачи, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Быструю сортировку здесь, думаю, все знают. А что именно вы сами сделали? Есть какие-то идеи по поводу алгоритма?

Comment: В том и дело что и поставленная задача не достаточно ясна, вот и обратился сюда, может кто-то поможет с ее решением, я же подробно его изучу и буду иметь виду в будущем.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/377974/ - вот же ваш старый вопрос. Обновили бы его, что ли.

Comment: Может кто-то помочь?

Comment: @qwesc, в чем помочь? Как найти подходящие пары в 2-х уже *отсортированных* (сортировку Вы уже написали) массивах?

Перебираете болты. Сравниваете очередной болт с гайками, пока они меньше болта и выбрасываете их (на грузила). Если подошел, то скручиваете и откладываете пару. Иначе выбрасываете болт. Повторяете, пока не закончились.

--

В принципе это очень похоже на слияние 2-х массивов (merge).

Answer (score 1):

Решить поставленную задачу можно двумя способами:

1. Итеративное решение
2. Рекурсивное решение

Вот тут в подробностях описаны два способа решение вашего вопроса, смотри [тут](http://learnc.info/algorithms/quicksort.html)

Comment: Довольно забавно видеть код (по ссылке), где заботятся о переполнении индекса (вследствии решения о беззнаковом типе индекса `size_t`, видимо от желания сортировать в т.ч. и "гигантские" массивы), но совершенно не думают об оптимизации размера стека.

Просто сначала надо расправляться с более короткими отрезками.

В стек заносим сначала более длинный отрезок, а потом более короткий (а для рекурсивной реализации сначала отправляем на сортировку более короткий).

Такаяя оптимизация позволит выделить память под стек (для  итеративной версии) однократно.